# Sorting xml file by subelement text using ElementTree in python

Tags: xml, sorting, elementtree

I am new in python.. please help me to sort given XML file using element Tree in python. I want to sort given file by date..

```
<record>
    <doc>
        <title> Mae Nee Nee </title>
        <name> b1 </name>
        <name> a1 </name>
        <year>2019</year>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <title> Mae Nee Lee </title>
        <name> A </name>
        <name> B </name>
        <name> C </name>
        <year> 2000 </year>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <title> Mae Nee Nee </title>
        <name> D </name>
        <year> 2011 </year>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <title> 1ee 2ee </title>
        <name> N </name>
        <year> 2007 </year>
    </doc>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
tree = et.parse('record.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
data = []
for elem in root.findall('doc'):
    key = elem.findtext('year')
    key = key.strip()
    data.append((key, elem))
data.sort()
root[:] = [ item[1] for item in data ]
tree.write('record_new.xml')
```

Note `key = key.strip()` instruction.
I added it because I noticed that your *year* tags contain surrounding spaces,
but the sort should be performed on just the year number.

Actually, you should rather take care of removing any surrounding spaces
in your XML tags.